# How to extract one value from 1-element collection in JMeter?

Tags: variables, select, jmeter

First, I do this select: 
`SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Person where Name=${NAME} AND YOB=${YOB};`
I need to do SQL request in JMeter:
`select * from Person where ID=${ID}`, where ${ID} is global variable returned in first select. First select returns collection, but there is only 1 value. How to extract this value and assign it to variable?

Comment: What sampler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) you can refer the value as `$A1`

```
A_#=2 (number of rows)
A_1=column 1, row 1
A_2=column 1, row 2
C_#=2 (number of rows)
C_1=column 3, row 1
C_2=column 3, row 2
```

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) for more tips and tricks on database testing with Apache JMeter.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: SELECT * from person where ID=${ID_1}

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the many [post-processor components](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract values from your response. In your case the [Regular Expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) is likely most suitable.